# Download files Configuration Error Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, .net-assembly

I've spent long time trying to figure out what the cause of this exception, I have an asp.net mvc app hosted on IIS 7.5 server and I have a couple of uploaded pdf, csv files.
When hitting the file URL to view or download a strange exception get thrown. The client is using a couple of DevExpress controls in the UI the following exception is encountered:

> Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DevExpress.Utils.v16.2, Version=16.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\eqaitweb\web.config    Line: 67
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'DevExpress.Utils.v16.2, Version=16.2.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you see `DevExpress.Utils.v16.2` assembly in your bin folder?

Comment: yeah its available in the bin folder

Comment: Then it seems we have something wrong with the configuration file. Do you have more detailed logs? Error details are hidden from outside, you can login to the server and try to load the file again